# Alpine linux azure python library dependency issue

Tags: python, azure, ansible

I keep getting the error that I don't have the required azure python libraries installed, even though I used `pip install azure and ansible[azure]`. There's only python3 pip installed.

Error:

```
{"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to import the required Python library (ansible[azure] (azure >= 2.0.0)) on runner-xxurkrix-project-31850574-concurrent-0's Python /usr/bin/python3. Please read the module documentation and install it in the appropriate location. If the required library is installed, but Ansible is using the wrong Python interpreter, please consult the documentation on ansible_python_interpreter"}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Try installing the dependency using ansible, to make sure that they are installed by the same user ansible is using to run the dependency.

Put this in your role before you are using it:

```
- name: Install required pip packages
  pip:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: present
  loop:
    - azure
    - ansible[azure]
```

Depending on where you execute the commands, e.g. on your local machine (localhost) or on a remote instance, you will have to adapt the task accordingly. Do not hesitate to post a comment to clarify.